# Binding multiple actions to span using EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, action

i have a span decorated with a disclosure triangle. When the user clicks on the triangle the span expands and displays its content. For ADA purposes, I would like that span to also expand when the user presses the enter key. Is it possible for this to happen? I've found a few links that say its not supported, but i did find one link that says its possible in more recent versions of Ember:
["Multiple actions on element"](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/11373)

But I've not been able to get this to work in 1.13.5.
Here's what I have:

```
{{#if isCollapsed}}
        <span class="control expanded" {{action "expand"}} {{action "expand" on="enter"></span>
    {{else}}
        <span class="control collapsed" {{action "collapse"}}></span>
    {{/if}}
```

The default action of clicking works, but is not fired when the Enter key is press. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What you'll need to do is this:

```
{{#if isCollapsed}}
    <span class="control expanded" {{action "expand"}} {{action "expand" on="key-press"></span>
{{else}}
    <span class="control collapsed" {{action "collapse"}}></span>
{{/if}}
```

You can see the complete list of events that Ember.js listens to [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_event-names), but they need to be changed from camelCase to hyphenated like I did above. And as Kristjan stated, you'll need to check that it's the enter key that's being pressed in your event.

That being said, what you're trying to do, probably won't work. The keyPress event is only emitted on an element that has focus. More than likely, your span element won't have focus. You could try giving it focus, but it'll loose it the moment the user clicks anywhere else.

You could try setting up a special handler in the view for that route.

Also, may I suggest switching to:

```
{{#if isCollapsed}}
    <span class="control expanded" {{action "toggleCollapsed"}} {{action "toggleCollapsed" on="enter"></span>
{{else}}
    <span class="control collapsed" {{action "toggleCollapsed"}}></span>
{{/if}}
```

Then in your action you can just do:

```
toggleCollapsed: function() {
    this.toggleProperty('isCollapsed');
}
```

Much simpler to just have one event. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, because of ADA concerns, the span can't have focus. We test against NVDA as a screen reader and we don't want the span to be read by NVDA, so we don't give it focus. I tried using the keyDown event handler, but that fires on all of the spans. There are several on the page and causes them all to expand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyDown event that gets triggered when the component is active

```
   keyDown: function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode === 13) { // enter
            this.set('isCollapsed', !this.get('isCollapsed'));
        } 
    },
```

Comment: It might be important: the keyDown event will fire on view only if it's focused.